# Google Data API very slow to read large spreadsheet

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, gdata-api

I am using the Google Data API for .net (https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) to read data from some Google Docs spreadsheets.

I have found that reading from a large spreadsheet ( > 14000 records) takes a very long time, several hours, before returning the data.

The code I'm using is below, is there another method to use to read the data, or am I missing something else to speed up this process?

```
public void ReadSpreadsheet(string applicationName, string title, string sheetName, string cellRange, string userName, string password)
{
    var service = new SpreadsheetsService(applicationName);
    service.setUserCredentials(userName, password); 

    SpreadsheetEntry spreadSheetEntry = GetSpreadsheetByTitle(service, title);
    WorksheetEntry workSheetEntry = GetWorkSheetByTitle(spreadSheetEntry.Worksheets, sheetName);
    AtomEntryCollection list = GetCells(service, workSheetEntry, cellRange);
}

public static SpreadsheetEntry GetSpreadsheetByTitle(SpreadsheetsService service, string title)
{
    var query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
    query.Title = title;

    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

    return (from SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries
        where title.Equals(entry.Title.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        select (entry)).FirstOrDefault();
}

public static WorksheetEntry GetWorkSheetByTitle(WorksheetFeed feed, string title = null)
{
    return (from WorksheetEntry entry in feed.Entries
        where title != null && title.Equals(entry.Title.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        select (entry)).FirstOrDefault();
}

public static AtomEntryCollection GetCells(SpreadsheetsService service, WorksheetEntry entry, string range)
{
    AtomLink cellFeedLink = entry.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.CellRel, null);
    var query = new CellQuery(cellFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
    query.Range = range;
    query.ReturnEmpty = ReturnEmptyCells.yes;

    // this line is what takes the most time
    CellFeed feed = service.Query(query);

    return (feed.Entries);
}
```